# Ionic 4: Redirect to route with id param

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-routing, ionic4

Let's say in our hero angular 7/ionic 4 hero app we have a `HeroDetailsRoutingModule` with 2 Tabs, the `SuperpowersPage` and the `CostumePage`.

Now we want to define the `SuperpowersPage` as default tab.

So I tried to set up my HeroDetailsRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs/',
        component: HeroDetailsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'superpowers',
                loadChildren: './superpowers/superpowers.module#SuperpowersPageModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'costume',
                loadChildren: './costume/costume.module#CostumePage'
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/heroes/:heroId/tabs/superpowers',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/heroes/:heroId/tabs',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

Of course that does not work because we don't have the `:heroId` in this module. What is the correct way to redirect in this case? I tried to do a relative path instead (e.g. `redirectTo: './tabs/superpowers'`) but that did not work either. I have the feeling to commit some obvious mistake but I don't get it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem this way

In HeroDetailsRoutingModule define Routes as

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: HeroDetailsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'superpowers',
                children:[
                 { path : ':heroId',
                  loadChildren: './superpowers/superpowers.module#SuperpowersPageModule'
                 }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'costume',
                loadChildren: './costume/costume.module#CostumePage'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'tabs/superpowers',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

in hero-details.page.ts set value of heroId

```
heroId =  <value>// get the value of heroId
```

Then in hero-details.page.html file access tab as

```
<ion-tab-button tab="superpowers/{{heroId}}">
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you pass :heroId to path 'superpowers' it should work. What happens when you try this ...

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs/',
        component: HeroDetailsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'superpowers/:heroId',
                loadChildren: './superpowers/superpowers.module#SuperpowersPageModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'costume',
                loadChildren: './costume/costume.module#CostumePage'
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/heroes/:heroId/tabs/superpowers',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/heroes/:heroId/tabs',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

Comment: Hmmm unfortunately the problem stays the same: Cannot redirect to '/heroes/:heroId/tabs'. Cannot find ':heroId'